# StartApp not displaying banners

Tags: android, libgdx, startapp

I've added StartApp in my project. I've done all things that were written in some tutorials. But, there are no banners appearing in my application.

I've added these into my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >

    <com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
      android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.android.DEV_ID"
    android:value="MyID there"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.startapp.android.APP_ID"
    android:value="gameID there>"/> 

    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.eula.EULAActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />

    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity" 
    android:taskAffinity="com.LightStealing.android.AppWall"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />

    <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:taskAffinity="com.LightStealing.android.AppWall"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Also I've put some lines in layout file:

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.banner3d.Banner3D
    android:id="@+id/startApp3DBanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And there is an `onCreate()` things:

```
 StartAppSDK.init(this, "myID", "gameID", true);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And I get a normal image in graphical layout.

But I get "Not active" status in StartApp dashboard and **nothing** in my game.

Maybe the problem is that my game is now on alpha test in Google Play and not published as working project or in anything else. I don't even know because it's the first time I'm trying do work with StartApp.

What steps are needed to get my game working in StartApp?

Comment: They have a good documentation on github: https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all

```
<com.startapp.android.publish.banner.Banner 
  android:id="@+id/startAppBanner"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

you do not need the above code in your manifest file, second of all, have you referenced your startapp add to load your add? it goes something like `startapp.loadAdd();` or `startapp.showAdd();` i have seen it before or so, do it after the findViewById to find your startbanner id..

Comment: can you explain with the real code? i have call startAppBanner.showAd() but banner still not shown

Comment: @zihadrizkyef have did you call `startapp.loadAdd()` before ? its been 3yrs if it doesn't work let me know so i go check

Comment: Sorry, i was though that i should call `StartApp.loadAd()`. But it turns out that i have to instantiate its class